# Can we use Angularfire with a natively hosted ionic app?

Tags: ionic4, angularfire2

I am building an ionic application that I hope to deploy as an android and ios application. I wish to use firebase so I was wondering if angularfire would still work or do I need to use a Cordova plugin?

Comment: npm i @angular/fire   , https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/fire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use AngularFire in your Ionic Mobile Android or iOS app.  That is how 99 percent of apps using Firebase are connecting. Its the most popular lib for working with firebase.